# if I have two for loops and one loops a constant value and the other iterates over array size M, is the time complexity O(M) or O(kM)?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have written a code that answers the question:

Given an integer array nums and an integer k, return the k most frequent elements. You may return the answer in any order.

Example 1:
Input: nums = [1,1,1,2,2,3], k = 2
Output: [1,2]

To summarise my code, I input each of the items in nums as keys in my dictionary, then simply do a count for each element by iterating over numbs, and storing the 'count' for object as values in the dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Solution:
    def topKFrequent(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:

        my_dict = defaultdict(int)
        top_two_final = []

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            my_dict[nums[i]] += 1

        sorted_values = sorted(my_dict.values(), reverse=True)

        for j in my_dict:
            for l in sorted_values[:k]:
                if my_dict[j] == l:
                    top_two_final.append(j)

        return set(top_two_final)
```

My question is around the TIME and SPACE complexity.

I believe both are O(Mk); where M is the size of the input nums, and the size of the array "sorted_values" (which is k)

But since k is a constant, is it right to conclude that both complexities are O(M)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that it's just **in best cases** O(M). **in worst case** when nums list is consecutive numbers [1,2,3...M] the big O becomes **O(MlogM)** due to sorting.